# QML ListView keep views when change model

Tags: qt, qml

I made a calendar utilizing QT's custom tumbler example. ( https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html )

```
Tumbler {
id: tumbler

contentItem: ListView {
    model: tumbler.model
    delegate: tumbler.delegate

    snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
    highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
    preferredHighlightBegin: height / 2 - (height / tumbler.visibleItemCount / 2)
    preferredHighlightEnd: height / 2 + (height / tumbler.visibleItemCount / 2)
    clip: true
    }
}
```

I made a good calendar using three tumblers from the example above. :)

However, the problem occurred when changing the month.

March is up to 31 days and April is up to 30 days. When the month changed, the model of the day part had to be changed.

Spin animation works when the model is changed.

I looked at the link below but it didn't help much.

[Qml Listview keep views when resetting model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188953/qml-listview-keep-views-when-resetting-model)

How can I remove the spin animation when changing the model?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: do you change the model?

Comment: Hi Ryu, for your day model do you use one per month (12 'day' models) or one for the whole year? You could perhaps use a signal when the month tumbler is changed to cause the model of your day tumbler to go to the beginning `currentIndex[0]`

Comment: If I understand your question correctly; are you 1) Trying to reset the 'day' tumbler to '1' when the day changes? 2) restrict the day tumbler model to either 28/29/30/31 'days' depending on the month/year? for either you would want to convert the string of numbers to a date object to then either add or edit the day

Answer (score 0):

If you still have not found a solution, my advise here is to use model class API to change it without overwriting.
Particularly, use `tumbler.model.remove(...)` and `tumbler.model.append({ ... })` combined with `model: ListModel {}`. You need to call them in the handler of month selection change.